# Importing React First vs Second

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Why does the following code work:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
```

But when I switch the order around, this DOES NOT work:

```
import { useState }, React from "react";
```

And I receive the following error. They are seemingly exactly the same commands just reversed in order.
[image]

For reference, here's the entire file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import { useState }, React from "react";

import MoviesList from "./components/MoviesList";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    function fetchMoviesHandler() {
        fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/films")
            .then((rsvp) => {
                return rsvp.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                const transformedMovies = data.results.map((movie) => {
                    return {
                        id: movie.episode_id,
                        title: movie.title,
                        openingText: movie.opening_crawl,
                        releaseDate: movie.release_date,
                    };
                });
                setMovies(transformedMovies);
            });
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <section>
                <button onClick={fetchMoviesHandler}>Fetch Movies</button>
            </section>
            <section>
                <MoviesList movies={movies} />
            </section>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: One is legal syntax, the other isn't. You don't have an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default imports should always be stated first, as the documentation says. You can check the documentation:

Node.js: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-specifiers

JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import